# organise a dropped element into another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project that works like that. I drag and drop some elements to some droppables and take the out again to the middle. Every droppable can have many dragged elements inside. it works fine when i work with one element, but whene it is more then one , it didn't , i didn't know how to make the two elements draggable and drop them both into the droppable and appears there fine . here is the funtion :

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).draggable({ cursor: 'move'});
    $( ".drop" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this);
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "height", "50%" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "width", "50%" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).find( "p" ).html( "cool!" );


      },
      out: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "drop" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped! out" );
$( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "height", "400px" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "width", "370px");              
               $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).find( "p" ).html( "Drag me to my target" );

      }
    });

  $( ".dropLeftRight" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this);
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "height", "50%" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "width", "50%" );

              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).find( "p" ).html( "cool!" );


      },
      out: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "drop" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped! out" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "height", "400px" );
              $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).css( "width", "370px");

               $( "#myDIV1,#myDIV2" ).find( "p" ).html( "Drag me to my target" );

      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle so we can see the issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bj3m24ks/3/ i couldn't add the jquery . just add it and check the issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bj3m24ks/4/